Find <td> in modal and use its ID
Using Intraweb.
I create a table on runtime, in modal, has ID, Table has ID and every td has unique ID.
I get a return van the Ajaxcall, but not the ID from the td which was selected.
With a table in the mainscreen (lower script) it works fine.
<div class="modal show" id="View" style="text-align: center; display: block;" aria-modal="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content BG">
            <div class="modal-header center CH"><b>List</b></div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <span class="LDATACSS" id="LDATA" style="" title="">
                    <table id="ViewTable" class="fs" style="width:100%">
                        <tbody>
                            <tr id="1">
                                <td id="VW1">Cell 1</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr id="2">
                                <td id="VW2">Cell 2</td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
    <!-- used by table in modal "View" and I cannot find the ID of the clicked <td> -->
    $('#View').on('click', function () {
        var vc=$(this).closest("td")
        ajaxCall("IH", "Params=" + "VW"+vc.attr('ID'))
    });
    <!-- used by table in main screen, this works fine-->
    $('table td').click(function () {
        var c = $(this).closest("td")
        if (Number(c.attr('ID')) > 0) { c.addClass("Select") }
        ajaxCall("IH", "Params=" + c.attr('ID'))
    });
</script>

I need the syntax how to retrieve the ID of the <td> and send it with the Ajaxcall

In this click handler:
$('#View').on('click', function () {
  var vc = $(this).closest("td")
  ajaxCall("IH", "Params=" + "VW"+vc.attr('ID'))
});

The reference to this refers to the element handling the click, which in this case is the #View element.  It doesn't have a "closest <td>" so nothing matches that and the resulting call to .attr('ID') returns undefined.
You can keep the click handler on the #View element, but also use event delegation (adding a second selector to .on()) to target clicks from those <td> elements.  That would make the <td> itself the reference for this (in which case you don't even need to use closest().
For example:


$('#View').on('click', 'td', function () {
    //                 ^--- using event delegation
    var vc = $(this);  // <--- remove the call to closest()
    console.log("Params=" + "VW"+vc.attr('ID'));
});
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="modal show" id="View" style="text-align: center; display: block;" aria-modal="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content BG">
            <div class="modal-header center CH"><b>List</b></div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <span class="LDATACSS" id="LDATA" style="" title="">
                    <table id="ViewTable" class="fs" style="width:100%">
                        <tbody>
                            <tr id="1">
                                <td id="VW1">Cell 1</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr id="2">
                                <td id="VW2">Cell 2</td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>




Brilliant, this works fine, thank you

console.log(\Params=VW${this.id}`)`
